# Normed Vector Space, open ball contained in subspace

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I was reading my measure theory book and came across a statement that I was a bit unsure of. I really do not have too much training in linear algebra, but was hoping to get some guidance on this:

If $U$ is a subspace of a normed vector space $V$ such that some open ball of $V$ is contained in $U$. Then is it true that $U=V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let's say that $B(a,r)$ denotes the ball of center $a$ and radius $r$, included in your subspace $U$. Then for every $x \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, you have $$x= \frac{2||x||}{r}\left[\left( \frac{rx}{2||x||}+a\right)-a \right]$$

which belongs to $U$, since both $\left( \frac{rx}{2||x||}+a\right)$ and $a$ belong to $B(a,r) \subset U$, and $U$ is a vector space. So $V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \subset U$.

And of course $0 \in U$, so you get $V \subset U$ and so $V=U$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Intuitively, since a subspace is closed under scalar multiplication you can extend this ball as much as you want. For example, assume $U$ contains a ball with radius $\epsilon$ around $0$. Then for every $0\ne v\in V$ we have $\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{v}{||v||}\in U$, and so:

$v=\frac{2}{\epsilon}||v||(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{v}{||v||})\in U$

The proof for a ball around any other point is similar.